# C# Windows Forms Binary File

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I have a method that is called when a user resets his password. When it is executed, it should see if the user exists in the binary file "PlayerDetails.bin".

The code works as intended and the password is reset, but an error is thrown despite this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Cannot access a closed file.

```
public static bool ResetPassword(string username, string password)
{
    //open file for read and write
    long pos = -1;
    bool found = false;
    Player readPlayer;
    Stream st;
    try
    {
        st = File.Open("PlayerDetails.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        while (st.Position < st.Length && !found)
        {
            pos = st.Position;
            readPlayer = (Player)bf.Deserialize(st);

            if (readPlayer.username.CompareTo(username) == 0)
            {
                found = true;
                readPlayer.password = password;

                st.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bf.Serialize(st, readPlayer);

                st.Close();
                st.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your while loop is still executing after the first iteration, then it will try to access the file you closed at the end of that if-statement. Hence why you would get that error.

Comment: You could use a `using` block: `using (BinaryWriter bf = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("PlayerDetails.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))`

Comment: Side note, according to MSFT, you should not call Close() on a Stream.   Just call Dispose.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Adam, please mark dko's answer. He had the right idea before I was able to put my comment down. =)

Comment: Ahh, i did not fully understand his answer, I do now @Sven. Although I will continue to use the code outside of the while loop rather than finally.

Comment: @Adam using a using block or a finally block is traditionally considered best practices. Not trying to start an argument but by putting it in the finally block, if the inner code throws an exception you still close the stream. That way if the program returns to open the stream later, you won't get a file access error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move the `st.Close(); st.Dispose()` out of the while loop.

```
Stream st= null;

try
{
    st = File.Open("PlayerDetails.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    try
    {
        while (st.Position < st.Length && !found)
        {
            pos = st.Position;
            readPlayer = (Player)bf.Deserialize(st);

            if (readPlayer.username.CompareTo(username) == 0)
            {
                found = true;
                readPlayer.password = password;

                st.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bf.Serialize(st, readPlayer);
            }
        }
    } 
    finally
    {
        if(st != null)
        {
            st.Close();
            st.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tried this, Error occurred under the close (however no error on the dispose part) , "Use of unassigned local variable 'st'"

Comment: fixed that. You should assign st = null first.

Comment: Use a `using` block instead, this code sample is pretty much the same that the compiler does for that statement.